# Manually uninstalling create-react-app because npm uninstall not working

Tags: npm, create-react-app, uninstallation

I try to uninstall create-react-app globally

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

But it gives me this result

```
up to date, audited 1 package in 264ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I have node version v17.3.0 (currently the latest stable version) and npm 8.3.0 (i've run npm update)

Is it sufficient to do this manually?

1. delete the alias `/usr/local/bin/create-react-app`   (find it with `which create-react-app`)
2. delete the folder that it refers to: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try clearing the `npx` cache with this command:

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

This worked for me.